# Long-running task without IHostedService running the entire life of the application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor-pages, ihostedservice

I have a website page that needs the option of performing an operation that could take several minutes. To avoid performance issues and time outs, I want to run this operation outside of the HTTP request.

After some research, I found [`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), which can be registered as a singleton using `AddHostedService<T>()`.

But my concern is that a hosted service is always running. Doesn't that seem like a waste of resources when I just want it to run on demand?

Does anyone know a better option to run a lengthy task, or a way to use `IHostedService` that doesn't need to run endlessly?

*Note that the operation calls and waits for an API call. And so I cannot report the progress of the operation, nor can I set a flag in a common database regarding whether the operation has completed.*

Comment: You can stop the hosted service from within the service after your task is finished. So basically it only runs while computing your task.

Comment: If use use Quartz.NET to schedule the job, its scheduler isn't burning CPU waiting for a job to be triggered. Adding Quartz.NET as a hosted service is [easy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz.Extensions.Hosting).

Comment: @madreflection: Thanks. I'm not sure if that makes sense to use a scheduler given that I will want the task to run immediately. Do you know if Quartz.NET requires the job to be a separate application? Or can it trigger a task within my Web app?

Comment: You can have it entirely within your ASP.NET Core application.

Comment: @Hille: How do you do that? Also, how would I start it again?

Comment: "Scheduler" is a more generalized term. The scheduler executes triggers, which can be "do it now, once" if that's what you need.

Comment: @JonathanWood [deleted] never mind, I was wrong

Comment: Basically, you create a "job" and add it to Quartz (durably, because there's no trigger) when adding it as a hosted service. Then you inject `ISchedulerFactory` in your page with the long-running task. Call `GetScheduler`, and then add a trigger to run the job, set to start immediately. You can use the `JobDataMap` to add parameters.

Comment: @madreflection: You lost me on that last comment. Add it to Quartz, durably, because there is no trigger? I thought the point of using Quartz.NET was it can act as a trigger.

Comment: Sorry, I initially misunderstood the confusion. When you configure Quartz.NET, generally, you add jobs and you add their triggers (like a CRON expression). In this case, you don't need to add a trigger initially because you don't know when it's going to be run. So you have to store the job durably (a nuance of how Quartz.NET works, I don't fully understand it). The trigger isn't created until your page needs to perform the long-running task. If the job wasn't stored durably, you get an exception at that point.

Comment: [Using Quartz.NET with ASP.NET Core and worker services](https://andrewlock.net/using-quartz-net-with-asp-net-core-and-worker-services/)

Answer (score 0):

One option to run a lengthy task on demand while avoiding performance issues and time outs is to use a **`message queue`**. You can have your Razor Pages website send a message to the queue when the operation is requested, and have a separate service, such as a **background worker**, consume messages from the queue and perform the operation. This allows you to decouple the task from the web request, and also allows for the possibility of adding more worker instances to handle the workload.

Another option is to use a **`task scheduler`** that runs on demand, such as **`Hangfire`**. It allows you to schedule background jobs and monitor their progress, which can be useful in your scenario where you cannot report the progress of the operation.

You can also use **`IHostedService`**, but you need to **make sure** that the service is only running when it is needed. You can use a `flag` or a `semaphore` to control whether the service is running or not. You can set the flag or semaphore when the operation is requested, and clear it when the operation is completed. The service can then check the flag or semaphore in its main loop, and exit if the flag is not set.

**In summary:**

`message queue`, `task scheduler`, and `IHostedService` with controlling `flag/semaphore` are all viable options for running a lengthy task on demand. The best option depends on your specific use case and requirements.

Comment: Thanks, but it would be helpful if your references were actual links. Anyway, `IHostedService` runs for the entire life of the application. How would you prevent it from running all the time, and how would you restart it if you could stop it?